# How can I make column groups be next to each other when generating CSV files in Python?

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm merging two JSON files into one CSV file, and want the output to have four columns of data next to each other (with a blank columns between the groups). However, the code is instead generating two columns one after another vertically.

I have two json files:

fileName1: Bio.json fileName2: Edu.json

```json
{
    "Name" :{
        "FN" : "jim",
        "MN" : "Mathew",
        "LN"  : "Novac"
    },
    "Birth Detail" : {
        "place": "Kiev",
        "Month" : "Aug",
    },
    "citizenship" : "Rus"
}
```

**Edu.json**2nd file

```json
{
    "College" : {
        "Name" : "SJC",
        "year" : "2010"
    },
    "Faculty": "Arts"
}
```

I used the below code to get csv but not the format I need:

```
        with open("FD.csv","a") as fr:
         writer = csv.writer(fr)
         header = ('Filename',(filename))
         writer.writerow(header)

         for value in data:
           # print (value)
            header2 = data.keys()
        
         for key,value in data.items():
            writer.writerow((key,"________"))
            if isinstance(value,dict):
                for key2,value2 in value.items(): 
                    writer.writerow((key2,value2))

            else:
                    
                    writer.writerow((key,value))
                    writer.writerow('\n')
                        
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    parse()
```

This is the desired output:

[image: The csv format i want: different json files side by side]

Comment: Please post text instead of images, especially the `json` data so we can reproduce your issue. Also indicate explicitly what the desired output is.

Comment: Hi @RJAdriaansen I have inserted json data as you suggested I made the changes, Thank you

Comment: Since the JSON-related code all works fine, this could probably be simplified to no longer include that code in the question. (Part of [mre] guidelines surround making questions _minimal_, taking out elements that aren't related to the specific problem at hand).

Comment: You're asking about a .csv, but you seem to want an xlsx that's laid out in a specific way - or are you really after a .csv with many empty fields?

Comment: Also, note that your `Bio.json` isn't actually valid JSON as given in the question -- it has an extra comma that isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't just one way to do this -- this is a question of how you structure your program logic, not really a question about Python itself; there's an infinite number of possible programs that would emit your desired output, so there isn't really such a thing as a canonical answer here.

That said, consider using iterators:

```py
import glob, itertools, csv, json

def kvPairsFromDict(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield (k, '')
            for k, v in kvPairsFromDict(v):
                yield k, v
        else:
            yield k, v

def kvPairsFromJson(filename):
    with open(filename, "rt") as f:
        yield ('Filename', filename)
        for k, v in kvPairsFromDict(json.load(f)):
            yield k, v

with open('out.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    inputFiles = glob.glob('CTM/*.json')
    inputStreams = [kvPairsFromJson(f) for f in inputFiles]
    for inputs in itertools.zip_longest(*inputStreams, fillvalue=('','')):
        row = tuple()
        for item in inputs:
            row += item + ('',)
        writer.writerow(row[:-1])
```

Comment: Marking this community-wiki to not accept any reputation, since I'm knowingly answering an off-topic question.